# Do infix functions in Haskell have type expressions ?

Tags: haskell

For example, `++`is essentially a function. I would expect that when I type `:t ++` or `:t prefixName` that I would obtain a type expression, but I receive a parse error. Is there a prefix for `++` or is there a special method to call `:t` for infix functions.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, the infix functions are functions, but to use them with `:t` you need to write it as a normal prefix function:

```
:t (++)
```

which gives

```
(++) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
```

This is part of the haskell syntax. To convert an infix function to prefix, surround it by parens, e.g.,

```
(+) 1 2
```

is equivalent to

```
1 + 2
```

Conversely, a normal prefix function can be used infix by surrounding it
with backticks, e.g.,

```
reverse `map` ["hello","world"]
```

is the same as

```
map reverse ["hello","world"]
```